# Exception: TypeInitializationException - The type initializer for ... threw an exception

Tags: c#, сервисы, .net, wcf

Добрый день, не давно начал изучать wcf(документации очень мало), попытался реализовать свой сервис и в результате чего получил исключение, над решение которого бьюсь очень долго, своими силами решить проблему не получается, если кто сможет подскажите пожалуйста.
**Сам сервис**

```
namespace TestService {

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://TestService")]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string name);
    [OperationContract]
    int Addition(int a, int b);
    [OperationContract]
    string TestString(string mas);
    //[OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]
   // IAsyncResult BeginServiceAsyncMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
    //string EndServiceAsyncMethod(IAsyncResult result);
}
//[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = true)]
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{

    public string SayHello(string name)
    {
        name = "zzzzzzzzzz" + name;
        return name;
    }
    public int Addition(int a, int b) 
    {
        b = b + a;
        return b;
    }

    public string TestString(string mas)
    {
        //string per = "22222";
        mas.Substring(1,3);
        mas.Remove(4);
        return mas;
    }
}
class Program : ServiceBase, IErrorHandler
{
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
    public System.Threading.Thread myThread;
    public static string CurDir=null;
    //System.Threading.Timer _Timer;
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
    }
    // HandleError. Log an error, then allow the error to be handled as usual.
    // Return true if the error is considered as already handled
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        using (TextWriter tw = File.AppendText(@"c:\logs\error.txt"))
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                tw.WriteLine("Exception: " + error.GetType().Name + " - " + error.Message);
            }
            tw.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
    public Program()
    {
        // Name the Windows Service
        ServiceName = "WCFTestService";
    }
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/WCFService");
        // Create the ServiceHost.
       // try
       // {
        ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
        //Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}");
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
        // provide the base address.
       try
        {
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), new Uri("http://localhost:8741/TestService"));
            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();
            CurDir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            int size = CurDir.Length;
            string necessary = CurDir.Substring(0, size - 21);
            System.IO.File.Create(necessary + "file1.txt");
            myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            myThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception error) 
        { Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + error.GetType().Name + " - " + error.Message);
        HandleError(error);
        }
    }
    void ThreadProc()
    {
        //Create in thread new form and timer  
        var _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        //_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        _Timer.Interval = 2000;
        _Timer.Start();
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;

        }
    }
  }
```

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>   <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />   </startup>   <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="c:\logs\Error.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>   </system.diagnostics>   <system.ServiceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="TestService.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="debug" contract="TestService.IWCFService"
                  bindingConfiguration="FileUploadServiceBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  bindingConfiguration="FileUploadServiceBinding"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8741/TestService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- buffer: 64KB; max size: 64MB -->
        <binding name="FileUploadServiceBinding"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 messageEncoding="Mtom"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferSize="65536"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>   </system.ServiceModel> </configuration>
```

В результате работы возникает ошибка.

> Exception: TypeInitializationException
> - The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility'
> threw an exception.

Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что в `InnerException`?

Comment: ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize

Comment: @SergD29: А остальные релевантные поля? Что ж из вас приходится информацию клещами тянуть? Что лежит в `ConfigurationErrorsException.Errors`?

Comment: У меня не получается самому вызвать ConfigurationErrorsException.Errors может где нибудь есть пример

Comment: заверни в Try Catch, в catch поставь брейкпойнт и просмотри поля, это же просто....

Comment: он мне пишет много подобного
"TestService.Program" does not implement interface member "System.Collections.ICollection.Count"
при подобном 
 public ICollection Errors (System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException ErrorException)
{
System.Collections.ICollection z = null;
return z;
using (TextWriter tw = File.AppendText(@"c:\logs\error.txt"))
            {
                if (ErrorException != null)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("Exception: " + ErrorException.GetType().Name + " - " + ErrorException.Message);
                }
                tw.Close();
            }

Comment: Сейчас пишет  This collection already contains an address with scheme http. There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
Parameter name: item